# Makefile how to use logical OR between prerequisites?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

My source files are organized nicely in a folder, that contains subfolders, that also contains source files.
The subfolders don't branch any further.
All object files are just meant to be created and stored in the same folder.

I don't want to manually list the name of the subdirs in the prerequisites when writing the target that generates my object files:

Right now this works:

```
$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/$(subdir1)/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/$(subdir2)/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

...
```

But I want it to look something like this:

```
$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c OR $(SRC)/*/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
```

I understand that the title most likely isn't the real question to be asked, but I'm looking for any solution. Also, I know that the `*` doesn't work as a placeholder here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can simplify the makefile you have by using [vpath](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search):

```
$(OBJ)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

vpath %.c $(SRC) $(SRC)/$(subdir1) $(SRC)/$(subdir2)
```

Then, if you really don't want to specify the subdirectories:

```
vpath %.c $(shell find $(SRC) -type d)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work if there happen to be `.c` files of the same name but different source subdirectories? (Although, neither will OP's version)

Comment: This works awesome. However, I run the makefile in Powershell, do you happen to know a windows alternative for the shell command?  :)

Comment: @M.M: Yes, I thought of that. If there is such a collision, then not only will the OP's makefile not work, there isn't even a way to resolve the problem from the command line.

Comment: @pluto9800: Sorry, I don't.

Comment: Time to download wsl

Comment: You don't need wsl or `shell`.  You can use the list of source files to find the list of directories to be searched.  However, unfortunately you didn't show us how you obtained your list of source files so we can't give you an example of what to do.

Comment: Certainly this cannot work if there are multiple files of the same name in different directories but that's a "feature" of the O.P.'s requirement that all the object files go into the same directory; there's no way to solve that problem given the requirements (this is why I never write my makefiles to put all object files into a single directory).